# Is it possible to use `require.context` to do dynamic imports for Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-component, dynamic-import

I am currently using `require.context` to load all my `.vue` components that do not have a filename ending with `Async`.

```
const loadComponents = (Vue) => {
    const components = require.context('@/components', true, /\/[A-Z](?!\w*Async\.vue$)\w+\.vue$/);

    components.keys().forEach((filePath) => {
        const component = components(filePath);
        const componentName = path.basename(filePath, '.vue');

        // Dynamically register the component.
        Vue.component(componentName, component);
    });
};
```

Now I want to load the my components that end with `Async` with `require.context` so I don't have to manually add them whenever I create a new component of this type.

Normally the dynamic import syntax would look like this:

```
Vue.component('search-dropdown', () => import('./search/SearchDropdownAsync'));
```

This will get resolved with a promise and import the component dynamically.

The problem that occurs is that when you use `require.context`, it will immediately load(require) the components and I am unable to use the dynamic import.

Is there any way to combine `require.context` with the dynamic import syntax of Webpack?

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: did you ever found a solution?

Comment: look here! https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7283#issuecomment-389281376

Comment: Thanks, at the time this question was posted it was about Webpack 3 though. Webpack 3 did not have this option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a fourth argument for `require.context` which can help with this.

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/9560af5545/lib/ContextModule.js#L14

```
const components = require.context('@/components', true, /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue)$/, 'lazy');
components.keys().forEach(filePath => {

  // load the component
  components(filePath).then(module => {

    // module.default is the vue component
    console.log(module.default);
  });
});
```

Comment: This solution is brilliant!