# Laravel Mix lazy load components from vue files

Tags: vue.js, webpack

im trying to load components from files rather than defining them within the `app.js`, but I also want to lazy load them, so trying to mix the 2 together.

So a lazy loaded component definiton would look like so:

```js
Vue.component(
    'carousel', 
    () => import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "carousel" */
        './components/carousel.vue'
    )
);
```

And registering the components using the files is like so:

```js
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
```

How can I combine this?

My current attempt is as follows, but of course I have missed out the `webpackChunkName` as no idea how to do that:

```js
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], () => import(files(key)) ));
```

This doesn't work however, I just get an error saying:

> WARNING in ./resources/js/app.js 9:11-29
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/index.sass

Comment: [Duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038473/is-it-possible-to-use-require-context-to-with-dynamic-imports-for-webpack) Tried flagging, but that didn't work due to bounty. Note that this only works with webpack 4 and newer.

Comment: @Excalibaard been trying to use this but it doesn't really solve the issue. There is no accepted answer and the only answer still loads all components even if they ain't used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up using the below code. I think after looking at it, it is similar to what Excalibaard posted, but I couldn't get that to work for me:

```js
const files = require.context('./components', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy');
files.keys().map(key => {    
    const name = key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    Vue.component(name, () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */'./components/' + key.slice(2)));
});
```

Comment: Good, thanks, i will try it out also because i'm still using the approach in my deleted answer